# How can I remove invalid characters from excel worksheet?

Tags: python

I am using python to write new worksheet to an existing excel files, the program works fine but when I try to manually open the excel file a window opens up to said that "we found a problem with some content" of the file. This issue is caused by invalid characters in the existing worksheets names (@.&-). I there a way to remove these characters from the existing worksheets before I write the new one? Please see my codes below. 
Thank you.

```
        book = load_workbook(out_path)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='w')
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='New_sheet',index = False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```